# Disabling AWS SDK Plugin Initialization on Startup

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, ide, environment, workspace

I'm looking for a way to stop my AWS SDK from initialzing on startup. The initialize takes awhile and hits my pc's performance pretty hard. Is it even possible to disable a plugin on the start up of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse:

> 1. go to: Window->Preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown
> 2. Under "Plug-ins activated on startup", uncheck whatever you don't want activated on startup.
> 3. Click OK

To Stop AWS SDK from downloading automatically:

> 1. go to: Window->Preferences->AWS Toolkit->AWS SDK For Java
> 2. Uncheck "Download new SKDs Automatically"
> 3. Click Ok